# Find text and replace entire cell value in Google Sheets with script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working with an external source as raw data which provides column headers with country codes + some other text (e.g. sessions US, active users US). I am looking for a script I can make a button for that replaces column headers as such:

- sessions US --> Is entirely replaced with --> United States of America
- active users --> Is entirely replaced with --> United States of America

In short it strips everything else and replaces US with United States of America as the new  cell value. So the script looks for 'part of' the cell value (US) and replaces the entire cell value with what I've configured. The script I got working is the following:

```
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
   .createTextFinder("US")
   .matchEntireCell(true)
   .matchCase(true)
   .matchFormulaText(false)
   .ignoreDiacritics(false)
   .replaceAllWith("United States of America");

  SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
   .createTextFinder("IT")
   .matchEntireCell(true)
   .matchCase(true)
   .matchFormulaText(false)
   .ignoreDiacritics(false)
   .replaceAllWith("Italy");
}
```

However, this script replaces 'US' with 'United States of America'. This means the following happens:

- sessions US --> Is partly replaced with --> sessions United States of America
- active users --> Is partly replaced with --> active users United States of America

Also good to note is that the script should work for multiple country codes at the same time (e.g. CA --> Canada, IT --> Italy). I got that working as well by simply copying the textfinder section over

I am simply not good enough with scripting to get this figured out as there is no use case I can find and reverse engineer myself. Hopefully, somebody here can help me out.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. When I saw your showing script, I thought that when the cell value is only "US", "US" is converted to "United States of America". For example, I thought that when the cell values are `sessions US` and `active users`, `US` and `us` are not converted to "United States of America". So, in your question, can I ask you about the detail of your current issue?

Comment: If you could post an example of your initial data and how you want that data to be convert4ed, then we can help you bridge the gap betweent the two, otherwise it's a little unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
function myFunction() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().createTextFinder("US").findNext().setValue('United States of America')
}
```

if you have multiple occurences, you can use

```
function myFunction() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    .createTextFinder("US")
    .matchEntireCell(false)
    .matchCase(true)
    .matchFormulaText(false)
    .findAll()
    .forEach(function (range) {
      range.setValue("United States of America");
    });
}
```

[findAll()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder#findall)

Comment: Thanks Mike, this did the trick, thank you very much!